# Does DataInputStream close wrapped InputSream when garbage collected?

Tags: java, stream, garbage-collection, finalizer

Considering Java code below:

```
void test(InputStream inputStream) {
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
    return;
}
```

when `test` method returns, dataInputStream will (sometime) be garbage collected. Does DataInputStream closes inner stream in its finalizer?

I failed to find any explicit statement if it does or not. Is there any official documentation about behavior? Can please you point if there is one?

Thanks.

**Edit:** I am not asking if closing DataInputStream closes inner stream too. I am asking what if I don't close and outer stream is garbage collected while inner still has references to it hence alive.

Comment: @tunaki the OP asked if the stream will be closed without an explicit close call because of a GC finalizer - and the answer is no, since there is no such finalizer

Comment: @wero Yes, that's what I ask. Is "No such finalizer" documented in some place? Is it implementation specific or mandatory by specification? Any links? Thanks.

Comment: @Volkan simply look at the source of `DataInputStream` and work up the hierarchy - there is no finalizer. The only classes in `java.io` with a finalizer are `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. Don't know if that is document anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation saying explicitely that the `DataInputStream` hasn’t a finalizer, but you could fill books with what a class *doesn’t* do. Since the purpose of a `finalize()` method is to release a resource a broken program forgot to release, only classes bearing a resource may have such a safety net. But `DataInputStream` doesn’t hold a resource, hence, hasn’t such a `finalize()` method.

It’s the underlying `InputStream` which might hold a resource and hence, only when the underlying `InputStream` becomes unreachable, a guarding cleaner may release the resource. It can be surely considered broken behavior when code outside your control spuriously closes your `InputStream` while you are still holding a strong reference to it.